# dagger2 field is not injected

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have an application (module + component) where

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(App app);

    Serializer getSerializer();

    ListOfCallingLists getListOfCallingLists();

    Context getContext();

    App getApp();
}
```

And

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private final App app;

    public AppModule(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    Serializer provideSerializer() {
        return new BinarySerializer();
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides
    App provideApp() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Singleton
public class ListOfCallingLists implements Serializable {
   ...
    @Inject
    public ListOfCallingLists(Context context,
                              Serializer serializer) {
        this.serializer = serializer;
        ...
    }
}
```

And `App` is the application, I registered it in manifest:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private AppComponent appComponent;

    public static App get(Context context) {
        return (App) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (appComponent == null)
            appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                    .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public AppComponent getComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

And finally the activity:

```
public class CallListsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    ListOfCallingLists list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // list here is null why?
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you injecting your Activity anywhere or how do you expect that `list` will be set? I only see you injecting your `Application`.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak No, I am assuming that application component will  be created once and `list` will be singlton. Can you advise how can I inject it?

Comment: At some point you need to call `component.inject(CallListsActivity.this)` for the fields to be injected, before you call that, it will always be `null`.

Comment: Found solution using this article https://blog.mindorks.com/introduction-to-dagger-2-using-dependency-injection-in-android-part-2-b55857911bcd

Comment: which version of dagger are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppComponent you need to add:

```
void inject(CallListsActivity callListActivity);
```

And in your CallListsActivity's `onCreate()` you need to tell how is your CallListsActivity injected.

For example, build your AppComponent and inject the activity, or you can use the new android injector: https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html